# Magento 2 How to pass collection of custom attribute using multiselect options from block

Tags: product-attribute

In list.phtml I am fetching newly created block's function.
like e.g.

```
$blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Custom\Module\Block\Entree');

$dataget = $blockObj->getProductdata($_productCollection);
```

Now I am using this $dataget variable by replacing of $_productCollection variable. But product count showing wrong.
How can I use below $call variable and return it from this block to my phtml, coz having problem as its in foreach loop.
I have created block, but collection is showing wrong.
Please find below my block code:

```
<?php
 /**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
  */

 namespace Custom\Module\Block;

class Entree extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
protected $_productRepository;
protected $attributeRepository;
protected $_categoryFactory;
private $registry;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository $attributeRepository,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->registry = $registry;
    $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    $this->attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
public function getProductdata($_productCollection)
{
     $currentCategory = $this->registry->registry('current_category');
     $ids = $currentCategory->getParentCategory()->getId();//$currentCategory->getId();

        $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($ids);

        $filterOptionIds = array();
        foreach($_productCollection as $products){
            if($products->getFilterType()){

                $filterOptionIds[][$products->getId()] = explode(",", $products->getFilterType());

            }
        }

        foreach ($filterOptionIds as $filterOption) {

            if($filterOption != ''){


            $coll = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToFilter('filter_type', array('eq' => $filterOption))->addCategoryFilter($category)->load();


            }
        }
```